# When I visit Ask Different, the listing of recent questions has some that appear to be written in the background

Tags: discussion

Recently when I visit Ask Different the list of questions has some that are faded out. I included a screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is?  I'm running High Sierra on my iMac. My browser is Safari.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Those are questions that have at least one tag which you ignored.**

From the Help Center article "[How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics)"

> Ignored tags downplay subjects you are not as interested in. Questions
>   with these tags are faded on the homepage and questions list, but are
>   still visible. If you want to completely hide questions with
>   containing your ignored tags, you may checking the "Hide Ignored Tags"
>   box in the "Preferences" tab of your profile's "Edit Profile &
>   Settings" section on most sites, or on the "prefs" tab of your profile
>   on certain other sites.

Comment: So we meet again!  I don't remember setting up any ignored tags but I suppose I did. How do I find which tags are ignored?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Go into your [Profile Page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/235922/jmh), the select "Edit Profile and Settings"  About a quarter of the way down, you'll see "Tag Watching and Ignoring".

Comment: You can also see them on the right column of the main page if you view 'Questions' rather than 'Home'